# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb. Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7

I wanted to install MySQL database for a Django Project which is developed in Python 2.7

I watched a lot of StackOverflow questions and responses... and I could not find a solution, but what i found is a mix between 2 answers:

I had this problem when I started the classic developing mode with **python manage.py runserver**, the server could not iniciate due to:

**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?**

I made a lot of module installations, I installed mysqlclient wheel and MySQL-python wheel, for that I had the wheel files on my computer, you can download on: [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/),

but this error could not stop, and I mixed 2 solutions, first I found a recommendation that was to run **python -m pip install mysqlclient**

And running this I got another error on wheel, so that, I ran the same command but instead mysqlclient I called the wheel file for mysqlclient (compatible version for my project)

so: **python -m pip install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl**

(the .whl file is the wheel and u have to download in the link below ([here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)), and then copy it on your project to be able call the archive (you could call it in every place, but it is faster))

Comment: Does it have to be Python 2.7? That's obsolete for years now, doesn't get updates or patches anymore, and is just outdated.

Comment: I talked about this version due to I had to program on this version in my job, due to the company app was not updated to last version yet, but off course, you are right, really deprecated version @Robert